# Android spacing two fragments on same screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have an activity that displays two fragments on the screen, one under the other. The top fragment is the user interface for the activity and the second is a custom ListView. I have two fragments that can fill the top slot, each a different size. The ListView is used for both.

The problem I'm facing is that there is a major gap between the top and bottom fragments. I know that it has something to do with the layout_weight attribute, and layout_weight is the only way I've seen to control how much of the screen a fragment commands.

What I would like to find out is if there is a way to dynamically resize the reserved fragment area when the fragment is loaded, or if I'm stuck with this ugly gap.

Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+android:id/realtabcontent1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+android:id/realtabcontent2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The two parts correspond to the two `FrameLayouts`? Also, use `@+id/theId` for non sdk ids(realtabcontent1 and realtabcontent2 are not in the sdk).

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out. The layout height of both FrameLayouts hosting the fragments should be set to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` and the `layout_weight` line should be removed. Then the spacing is handled dynamically on a fragment being loaded to that FrameLayout.